# Insert data through a viewgrid after clicking on CREATE (more than one viewgrid)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gridview, datagrid

I'm stuck on this situation and i dont understand how to make it works on MVC ASP.NET Core using C#

I created a viewgrid that allows me to Create, Update, Delete every single row shown in the grid. The problem is that everytime i click on CREATE it shows me a page where i can only write (manually) everything but instead of that i want my application to display another viewgrid (from a different database table) and allow the user to select the ROW or ROWS that he wants to add (something like a checkbox or whatever).

Take a look:

[image]

How can i do that?. I searched a lot but nothing really helped at all. Found something related to FORMS but not sure about that

**This is my CONTEXT cs file:**

```
public void CreateUser (User user)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Create_user", con)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", user.NAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST", user.LAST);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION", user.DESCRIPTION);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

---

**This is my Controller file:**

```
[HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int id, [Bind] User user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.UpdateAprobador(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dbContext);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

**This is my VIEW file:**

```
@model WebApplicationNewsan.Models.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NAME" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NAME" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NAME" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LAST" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LAST" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LAST" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DESCRIPTION" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DESCRIPTION" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DESCRIPTION" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hey pal, thank you for replying. I tried to make it work, thought about the possibility of using a matrix but not clue at all :(. Is it possible to achieve something like that?